# SQL view progress of query

Tags: mysql, sql, progress

Is there a way I can view the progress of a query? For example, SELECT queries that have to fetch large amount of data. If a table contains 100 rows, can SQL report which row is processing at the moment? That would be 1 to 100 progress.

I'm not wanting to view the progress in time left or something related with time because I find it impossible or I am wrong?.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It was a general DBMS question, but being more accurate, MySQL.

Comment: I'd assume because of the way DBMS load their data (execution plans and the like) it's very hard to determine where you are - especially if you aren't sure how many rows you are returning in the first place. Add to that the complexity of the execution plan, and also parallelism over multiple threads and you've got a "finger in the air" best guess. In most cases, if a query takes a long enough time to warrant a progress bar, it's probably not that well written (though this does depend on what it's supposed to do!)

Comment: @Charleh: in Oracle (Enterprise Edition) it is possible to monitor a running statement. Oracle will even show how far each step in the execution plan is.

Comment: Ah that's cool, wonder if there is a similar thing in MSSQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible!

By the way, note, that e.g. mytop - monitoring tool from CLI for MySQL and MariaDB has already implemented that function.

**(1) In MariaDB**

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                  | Progress |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
| 126 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |    0.000 |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
```

Progress: 
The total progress of the process (0-100%) (How to enable that? see [Progress Reporting](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/progress-reporting/) - page of MariaDB manual).

This function is introduced from **MariaDB 5.3**.

**(2) in MySQL**

Default list of query's attributes is e.g.:

```
Id: 3123
User: stefan
Host: localhost
db: apollon
Command: Query
Time: 0
State: NULL
Info: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

If you would like to monitor e.g. `ALTER TABLE` command progress in **InnoDB**, you can use:

```
SELECT EVENT_NAME, WORK_COMPLETED, WORK_ESTIMATED FROM events_stages_current;
```

Which will produce something like that:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| EVENT_NAME                                           | WORK_COMPLETED | WORK_ESTIMATED |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| stage/innodb/alter table (read PK and internal sort) |            280 |           1245 |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

BUT first you have to enable this mechanism:

```
UPDATE setup_instruments SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME LIKE 'stage/innodb/alter%';

UPDATE setup_consumers SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME LIKE '%stages%';
```

and of course you will have to have already enabled **performance_schema**.

Whole procedure is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/monitor-alter-table-performance-schema.html).

Ouch! I forgot this important link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema-progress-reporting.html, as of MySQL 5.7.9 several addons are available.

How to enable in cfg file:

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema-instrument='stage/%=ON'
performance-schema-consumer-events-stages-current=ON
performance-schema-consumer-events-stages-history=ON
performance-schema-consumer-events-stages-history-long=ON
```

How to check current state of process monitoring tools:

```
SELECT * FROM setup_instruments WHERE NAME RLIKE 'stage/sql/[a-c]';
SELECT * FROM setup_instruments WHERE
       ENABLED='YES' AND NAME LIKE "stage/%";
SELECT * FROM setup_consumers WHERE NAME LIKE '%stages%';
```

Notes:
If you get the error

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the PROCESS privilege for this operation
```

then you are probably connected as the anonymous user. Try running "select current_user" to see.

Comment: Note that while MariaDB progress reporting is very useful, it only applies to DDL commands like ALTER TABLE, not to SELECT statements as the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `show processlist;` in mysql, it will give you the time query has taken as well as the current step query is in like fetching,sending etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is analyze the [Execution Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) before run the query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL queries don't work that way. You can view significant period or execution times/dates and then evaluate the differences between start and finished or maybe split a query up and see how it affects the overall time taken.

I just don't think SQL reports back in that way and so a 'loading' idea *is a bit far-fetch*. Though I've only used a handful of SQL technologies...

Comment: Well, Oracle _can_ show the progress of a statement, even each step of the execution plan in percent.

Comment: Dang, one of the ones I've not had the pleasure of using yet. :(